# How to solve non-alignment of Delphi child form within parent form in XP

Tags: delphi, forms, vcl, alignment

I have a number of forms that 'host' other forms using ChildForm.Parent := HostForm and ChildForm.Align = alClient etc. Some child forms are host themselves for another child form. Under Windows 7, the alignment is fine but Windows XP sometimes leaves the child form visible but not client aligned. Touch the outer window frame to resize it by one pixel and it all springs aligned correctly. Is there a command I can send to the host form to ensure that the alignment has taken place properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take look at [Realign](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TWinControl.Realign) method. Look also at [AlignControls](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TWinControl.AlignControls) and [ArrangeControl](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TWinControl.ArrangeControl) to manually align the child control. Consider also using Frames instead of Forms if it is possible - they are designed for the job you described (but on the other hand have a number of inconveniences - for example lack of OnCreate event).

Best regards -- Spook.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem a few times and it seems it is often caused by faulty controls on the child form.

[How to avoid issues when embedding a TForm in another TForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385948/how-to-avoid-issues-when-embedding-a-tform-in-another-tform)