# How to make manual docking seamless / invisible?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, docking

I am trying to use docking as an alternative to embedding ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385948/how-to-avoid-issues-when-embedding-a-tform-in-another-tform)) a `TForm` into a `TWinControl` (in this case a `TTabSheet`).

The user shouldn't notice that there are two different forms at all.

How do I avoid the close button and "drag bar" at the top of the docked form?

A simplified version of my code:

```
var
  TabSheet: TTabSheet;
  Form: TSubForm;
begin
  TabSheet             := TTabSheet.Create(Self);
  TabSheet.DockSite    := True;
  TabSheet.PageControl := MainPageControl;

  Form := TSubForm.Create(TabSheet);
  Form.ManualDock(TabSheet);
  Form.Show;
end;
```

PS: I don't want to use a `TFrame` which would of course be another alternative.

**Update:**

In this specific situation I am now considering to use `TTabControl` instead of `TPageControl`, so I can put all the controls into the master form.

I am using MVC/MVA anyway so the logic is separated from the UI.

Comment: Your code works fine in my Delphi 2007 - no window title is visible in the page control

Comment: @gabr: You're right, my actually code has a `TPanel` between the tab sheet and the sub form.

Comment: I figured out whats going on: Acutally it seems the close button and "drag bar" are drawn by some third party (DevExpress) code.

Comment: You should delete this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close it, the code might still be useful to someone searching for a similar problem.